# Use different AuthenticationProvider depending on username and remote IP address

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-ldap

In a Spring Security 3.2 based application I need to authenticate users against two different providers, based on a certain pattern in their username AND their remote ip address.

In case they match certain rules, they should be authenticated against an `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`, otherwise with a standard `AuthenticationProvider` using an already exisiting custom implementation of `UserDetailsService`.

What do I need to extend ? `AuthenticationManager` or `AuthenticationProvider` ? Any example code would be highly appreciated :-)

Note: I have already successfully tried adding two `<authentication-provider />` nodes in `<authentication-manager />`, and this worked fine. But it bothers me that my Ldap-server is hit for every authentication attempt (even the ones which are not meant for it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a wrapper which does the check for the pattern/ip-address if it matches calls the delegate else return null.

```
public class FilteringAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    private final AuthenticationProvider delegate;

    public FilteringAuthenticationProvider(AuthenticationProvider delegate) { this.delegate=delegate;}

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        Object details = authentication.getDetails();
        String username = authentication.getPrincipal().toString();
        String remoteAddress = null;
        if (details instanceof WebAuthenticationDetails) {
            remoteAddress = ((WebAuthenticationDetails) details).getRemoteAddress(); 
        }

        if (matches(remoteAddress, username)) {
            return delegate.authenticate(authentication);
        }
        return null
    }

    private boolean matches(String remoteAddress, String Username) {
        // your checking logic here
    }       
}
```

Something like this. Then configure it in your security configuration and let it wrap the `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`.

```
<sec:authentication-manager>
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="filteringLdapProvider" />
    <sec:authentication-provider>
        <user-service ref="customUserDetailsService" />
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="filteringLdapProvider" class="FilteringAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg ref="ldapProvider" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapProvider" class="ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
...
</bean>
```

Something like this.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `delegate.authenticate(authentication)` will then effectively use my implementation of UserDetailsService ? And if `matches(remoteAddress, username) == false` I instantiate an `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` and pass it the `authentication` ?

Comment: No... As I mentioned you simply wrap your `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` with this one. It will only actually call the `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` if the match is true, else it returns `null` which is the trigger for Spring Security to call the next `AuthenticationProvider` in the chain.

Comment: See the modified answer.

Comment: Thanks for the additionnal details!