# Spring Security - Switch between Authentication Providers at Runtime (local database OR remote LDAP)

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

im currently working of a Spring MVC web application and we have been using authtication via a local database with an impl of the *AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider* class provided by spring security.

However, to secure the app further, we decided to allow users to authenticate via LDAP/AD server. This would not be a requirement and users can choose to enable this in the configurations in the portal itself.

Wondering how would one actually go around implementing this. Have found the *AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider*. However, just to add this additional authentication provider to the authentication manager would not suffice as weather or not it should be there should be determined at runtime by a flag in the database.

Would really appreciate any help in this area.

Thanks for reading:)

Comment: Look at this questions and its answer, that should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381893/use-different-authenticationprovider-depending-on-username-and-remote-ip-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably multiple ways to do this, but a simple approach would be to have two authentication providers to the authentication manager, authentication provider for local database first, LDAP authentication provider second.

To skip LDAP check at runtime, throw `AccountStatusException` (a subclass thereof, since abstract) from your local database provider. This makes the authentication manager skip further providers, in your case LDAP.

If you want the other way around for a user, set the password to blank or a random value in local database.

Comment: Hi holmis83 thanks for the response!! just wondering if i add an chain the authentication providers together under the auth manager and the the when i throw an impl of *AccountStatusException* will that void my login all together?!

Comment: @jiachen yes, that will fail the authentication altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Have two authentication providers, one for local database and one for LDAP. The Spring authentication manager will invoke the `public boolean supports(Class authentication)` method in each of the providers to see if the provider supports the Authentication class provided. So the `supports(Class authentication)` method is a perfect place for you to write your own custom logic to enable/disable a particular authentication provider.

Comment: This looks like a more proper solution than using exceptions to control the flow, as proposed by holmis83.