# Customize Spring Boot's default loginForm action

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm looking into ways to customize Spring Boot's default `.loginForm(...)` action. Here's my -simplified- config:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/account/login/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/account/login").successHandler(new WebAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/account/logout")).deleteCookies("remember-me")
                .and().requestCache().requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
                .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new SomeEntryPoint("/account/login"))
                .and().rememberMe().tokenRepository(...)
                .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(...)
                .and().addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    }
```

basically, I am happy with this configuration and posting to `/account/login` but I would like to add yet another constraint (e.g. check if IP of the user is in the database as authorized IP address) to the user verification step.

I was wondering where would be the correct place to put that piece of code, `UserDetailsManager` or `UserDetailsService` etc. seemed quite wrong, as I am looking to customize only the login action. Thanks!

Comment: I would definetely put it in your `UserDetailsService` implementation.

Comment: I believe that would be semantically wrong, `loadUserByUsername:UserDetails` should only be responsible for loading the `UserDetails` object if it exists, not verifying their Ip.

Comment: You can add it into antMatchers configuration, and then implements your custom permission methods

Comment: Create a method in a bean that checks the access that write a permission expression like `access('@yourbean.yourMetho(authentication')`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I do have a custom method security expression as: `hasAuthorizedIpAddress()` just like `hasRole('SOME_ROLE')`. If that's what you mean and if you could post a more complete answer, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: That is exactly what I meant. You can use the same expression to secure your URLs. Although I get the impression you want to make it part of the login functionality. For this you probably want to extend (or maybe wrap) the `AuthenticationProvider` to do the additional check (which is also the the better place to put that logic).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. I have posted an answer that I am not 100% satisfied of, but did the trick for now. Improvements and suggestions are welcome, of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer that I could come up with:

```
    public class IpAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

        private AuthenticationProvider delegate;

        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

            String address = ((WebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails()).getRemoteAddress();

            // Throw an AuthenticationException if there's a bad IP here

            return delegate.authenticate(authentication);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
            return delegate supports(aClass); 
        }

        public void setDelegate(AuthenticationProvider delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }
    }
```

to configure it:

```
    @Configuration
    public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

            IpAuthenticationProvider provider = new IpAuthenticationProvider();
            provider.setDelegate(authenticationProvider())
            auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {

            DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean());
            provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
            return provider;
        }
    }
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381893/use-different-authenticationprovider-depending-on-username-and-remote-ip-address), it was all there from the beginning.

Comment: The point is you aren't wrapping anything. What you want to do is create an implementation of the `AuthenticationProvider` which would actually wrap to original one. Then delegate all the methods to the wrapped `AuthenticationProvider` and in the `authenticate` method, before delegating, do the check. then you can reuse it regardless of the used `AuthenticationProvider`.

Comment: So instead of extending an implementation, I can indeed `@Autowire` one into it and delegate. Thanks!

Comment: That is what I also suggested initially (but apparently didn't explain that clearly).

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum. I have figured it out!

Comment: If that is your modified code it is still flawed. Your `supports` call should delegate to the `supports` method on the delegate. I would also suggest to use constructor injection instead of a setter, that way you cannot construct a `IpAuthenticationProvider` in an invalid state (you now can without calling the setter).

Comment: I forgot to update `supports` method in the answer, it was already delegated. As for injection, the code in the project is a little more complicated than shown above, and setter method seemed a better choice. Thanks!